# Transduce: Why this transduce doesn't print anything

Tags: clojure, transducer

I have the following code, and I have expected it to print `1,2,3,4` on console, and return `[true,true,true,true]`.
But it just return empty and doesn't print anything on console.

The logic is: it loop for `(0..3)`, `inc` every element by 1, so I got `(1..4)`, then run `(map (fn[x] (println x) true))` it takes 1 from the lazy sequence, print 1, and return true, and `take-while` will output the result to `[true]`, then take the next element of 2, print 2, return [true,true], etc. so the result should print 1,2,3,4 to console, and return `[true,true,true,true]`. But actually, it prints nothing and return `[]`. How to understand this?

```
(transduce (comp (take-while true?)
                 (map (fn[x] (println x) true))
           conj
           []
           (map inc (range 4)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because

> Composition of the transformer runs right-to-left but builds a transformation stack that is applied left-to-right (filtering happens before mapping in this example).

Look here for more :http://clojure.org/transducers